# Deleting uploaded files in Node.js with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, error-handling, mongoose, delete-file

I have a one-to-many relationship between two entities: courses and files.

So, the way I set it up my database is to use two separate collections: courses and files.

```
var CourseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    code: { type: String, required: true, unique: 1, uppercase: 1 },
    files: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'File' }]
    // more fields
});

var FileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true }
    // more fields
});
```

I have a working page that allows users to upload and add files within a course. As well, they can delete selected files on this same page.

My concern is when I delete selected files. After selecting the files that need to be deleted and clicking on the submit button, I send a DELETE request passing a list of file IDs. Below is my handler for deleting files:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

var models = require('../models');

exports.deleteFiles = function (req, res) {
    // loop through selected file-ids
    async.eachSeries(req.body.files, function (id, done) {
        // remove file from File collection
        models.File.findByIdAndRemove(id, function (err, file) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            } else if (!file) {
                return done();
            }
            // remove file reference from Course document
            req.course.files.pull(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id));
            req.course.save(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    return done(err);
                }
                var path = __dirname + '/../public/upl/' + req.course.id + '/' + file.name;
                // remove file from filesystem
                fs.stat(path, function (err, stats) {
                    if (err && err.code === 'ENOENT') {
                        return done();
                    } else if (err) {
                        return done(err);
                    }
                    if (stats.isFile()) {
                        fs.unlink(path, done);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    }, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            req.flash('failure', 'Unable to delete files at this time.');
        } else {
            req.flash('success', 'The files have been deleted successfully.');
        }
        res.redirect('/admin/courses/' + req.course.id + '/files');
    });
};
```

It's pretty messy as I have to do several steps for each file ID: delete the ID from the course's file array, delete the file from the actual collection, and delete the file from the filesystem. As well, I have some error handling code at the beginning of each step.

Can this be improved using less steps and/or better error-handling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it this way, much cleaner imho, using `each` and `waterfall`, to iterate over collection and pass *file* from *findByIdAndRemoveFn* function

```
var async = require('async');
var File = require('../models/File'); //assume it's File.js

exports.deleteFiles = function (req, res) {

    var files = req.body.files;
    var course = req.course;
    var prePath = __dirname + '/../public/upl/' + course.id + '/';

    async.each(files, function(fileId, cb) {
        async.waterfall([
            function findByIdAndRemoveFn(parallelCb) {
                File.findByIdAndRemove(fileId, function(err, file) {
                    if(err) return parallelCb(err);
                    parallelCb(null, file);
                });
            },
            function pullFn(file, parallelCb) {
                course.update({$pull: {files: fileId}}, function(err) {
                    if(err) return parallelCb(err);
                    parallelCb(null, file);
                });
            },
            function unlinkFn(file, parallelCb) {
                var path = prePath + file.name;
                fs.stat(path, function(err, stats) {
                    if(err) return parallelCb(err);
                    else if(stats.isFile()) fs.unlink(path, parallelCb);
                    else parallelCb();
                });
            }
        ], cb);
    }, function(err) {
        if(err) req.flash('failure', 'Unable to delete files at this time.');
        else req.flash('success', 'The files have been deleted successfully.');
        res.redirect('/admin/courses/' + course.id + '/files');
    });
}
```

Comment: I like this. It's much cleaner and readable. And I never knew you can give name anonymous functions.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using `async.auto` method:

```
async.eachSeries(req.body.files, function (id, done) {
    async.auto({
        removeFileRecord: function(cb) {
            models.File.findByIdAndRemove(id, function (err, file) {
                if (err) return cb(err);
                return cb(null, file);
            });
        },

        pullFileFromCourse: ['removeFileRecord', function(results, cb) {
            // do nothing if file did not exist
            if (!results.removeFileRecord) return cb(null);

            req.course.files.pull(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id));
            req.course.save(cb);
        }],

        unlinkFile: ['pullFileFromCourse', function(results, cb) {
            var file = results.removeFileRecord;

            var path = __dirname + '/../public/upl/' + req.course.id + '/' + file.name;
            // remove file from filesystem
            fs.stat(path, function (err, stats) {
                if (err && err.code === 'ENOENT') {
                    return cb();
                } else if (err) {
                    return cb(err);
                }
                if (stats.isFile()) {
                    fs.unlink(path, cb);
                }
            });
        }];
    }, done);
}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        req.flash('failure', 'Unable to delete files at this time.');
    } else {
        req.flash('success', 'The files have been deleted successfully.');
    }
    res.redirect('/admin/courses/' + req.course.id + '/files');
});
```

Comment: fix `return cb(file);` on _removeFileRecord_ to `return cb(null, file);`